# removed fragment still visible

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am developing a kiosk app so it's takes over the tablet. Single activity with bunch of different fragments. I commit a fragment in the oncreate of the activity. Then when the device is connected to bluetooth it will load a new fragment by removing the old one and adding a new one instead (calls a function cancelFunc()). The issue that I am having is that the first fragment is still visible after removal. My logs show that it is actually removed and a new fragment is attached instead but I can't see the new one or any other that are attached later. However, when I tap the screen it shows the new fragment. A bit strange and I wonder what I am doing wrong. It is something that only happens on the fragment attached on the oncreate of the activity. The code is rather long so I'm just showing you a few important parts. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.backbone);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new SystemDownFragment(), "SystemDownFragment");
    ft.commit();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "adapter is null");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}

public void cancelFunc() {
    Log.d(TAG, "cancelFunc()");

    removeFrag();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new StartupFragment(), "StartupFragment");
    ft.commit();
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}

private void removeFrag(){
    Log.d(TAG, "removeFrag()" + getActiveFragments().size());
    if(getActiveFragments().size() > 0) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < getActiveFragments().size(); i++) {
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
            ft.remove(getActiveFragments().get(i));
        }
        ft.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onAttachFragment");
    fragList.add(new WeakReference(fragment));
}

public List<Fragment> getActiveFragments() {
    ArrayList<Fragment> ret = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    for(WeakReference<Fragment> ref : fragList) {
        Fragment f = ref.get();
        if(f != null) {
            if(f.isVisible()) {
                ret.add(f);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

My logged data shows the following:

```
MainActivity: onCreate()
MainActivity: onAttachFragment
MainActivity: onStart()
MainActivity: onResume()
MainActivity: Bluetooth Connected
MainActivity: cancelFunc()
MainActivity: removeFrag()1
MainActivity: onAttachFragment
```

Comment: are u able to see the new fragment ?

Comment: Use ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new StartupFragment(), "StartupFragment"); instead of ft.add();

Comment: I can't see the new fragment until I tap on the screen. After that it becomes visible. For every other fragment that I add and remove throughout the code, this works with no problems. But it has problems with just this very first fragment in activities onCreate().

And I have been trying to avoid replace cause I usually have one or two fragments attached at the same time and it is easier for me to just remove them all when necessary and add new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear or remove all views from the current fragment, and then replace new fragment in Layout.

Like this one, try this

```
myLayout.removeAllViews();

AddNewFragment new = new AddNewFragment();

this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, new, "").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: This actually could be it. I'll try this tonight and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: You r Welcome. :) Plz accept my Answer if its really helpfult to you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove fragment you just need to call activity onBackPressed() method, since this method perform operation of going back thus it will remove your current fragment from activity, and then you can add another one. So update your removefrag() method with below code.

try this,

```
void removeFrag(){
   onBackPresssed();
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10767144)

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: He asked to remove fragment, and I mentioned the code which do the same.. whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: there is nothing wrong but there is something inconvenient with it, as here in SO all the answers without clarification are deleted because the community point is to gain knowledge not only solve problems, so kindly explain why your code is solving his problem as this will give benefits to him and to anyone else see your answer.

Comment: thanks for information. I have updated my answer, now I clarify why my code will work.. thanks again :)

Comment: For the backpress to work then the fragment would have to be on backstack though, right? So I would have to call addToBackStack(null) before commiting the fragment. So far I have been avoiding adding anything to backstack cause my app uses bunch of different fragments and it is much easier for me to not have anything on backstack and just remove them all, and add new ones.

Comment: no issue... if you added framgent in backstack this function sure work, if you have not... then use replace() method of FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 0):

It might solve your problem but it also good practice for what you want to do; Use `ft.replace(...)` on your FragmentTransaction instead of adding and removing...

Comment: Could you explain why that's a good practice? My app has multiple fragments being displayed at the same time and I found that it was easier for me to remove all fragments and display new ones.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace new fragment when back pressed in that activity .

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new_fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
```

}

Comment: This is a kiosk app. It fully takes over the app and we are hiding the back buttons. so I can't rely onBackPressed()